# How to pass input json along with S3 event trigger in AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to pass some input json along with S3 event trigger data to AWS lambda function.

So  i would like to configure AWS lambda with S3 file put Event and add input target as Constant ie {"job_name":"job1"} ?Is this even possible as far as i know im able to do this using Cloudwatch Event by passing input constant Json but it replaces the actual Cloudwatch event data

Would like to know how can i pass input json along with S3 event trigger data to AWS lambda function

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible. When the S3 event is triggered it will replace the event object with the one sent from S3.

As an alternative approach, you can store some details with object metadata in s3 and access from Lambda.